# I would like to check if the concatenation of two columns in my first csv file do not exist in my second csv file in my Karate test

Tags: karate

- def concatField = {'#(responseartikel[].Kurztext_1 + responseartikel[*].Kurztext_2)'}
- match concatField !contains expected

But I get an error: "net.minidev.json.parser.parseexception unexpected character ( }) at position 66."

Is there another way to define this concatenated field without writing a java utility?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is confusing because you talk about "unique" and then "do not exist". I'll for now focus on "unique".

And I'll ignore the CSV part of your question. You already know how to convert CSV to JSON, so I'll focus on JSON.

Karate has a `karate.distinct()` API to remove duplicates. So here is a working example:

```
* def list1 = ['abc', 'def', 'abc', 'def', 'ghi']
* def res1 = karate.distinct(list1)
* match res1 == ['abc', 'def', 'ghi']

* def list2 = [1, 2, 1, 2, 3]
* def res2 = karate.distinct(list2)
* match res2 == [1, 2, 3]
```

Now you can just do a before and after match to see if the list changed (or not). The rest is up to you. Also note that you can transform existing JSON into simple arrays of primitives, refer: https://github.com/intuit/karate#json-transforms

If this answer doesn't answer your question, please assume that what you want is not supported by Karate and you should look for another tool.